# MySQL Group selected rows on Select

Tags: mysql

Suppose I've got the following table:

```
Room | Seats | Occupied
-----------------------
a1      20       10
b2      15       15
c3      45       30
d4      20       15
e5      10       10
```

I have a trouble (just have no idea how that can be done) generating a SELECT statement that will merge some of the rooms and will sum up their values and will return the following:

```
Room | Seats | Occupied
-----------------------
a1      20       10
b2c3d4  80       60
e5      10       10
```

How can this be done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It should "merge" the rows as I showed in the question.

Comment: There is no rule. Suppose that the values for the Room to be grouped will always be b2, c3 and d4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select room,
       sum(seats) as seats,
       sum(occupied) as occupied
from your_table
group by case when room in ('b2', 'c3', 'd4') 
              then 'b2c3d4'
              else room
         end
```